# LPR Utility for Windows 98

Tags: networking, printing, tcpip, windows-98, lpr

I'm trying to print to a network printer through TCP/IP in windows 98, however, windows 98 does not support printing to a TCP/IP port, so I read that I can do it through something called LPR.

Where can I find a software that allows me to print to a LPR print queue from Windows 98? Your help is much appreciated? Any hints would be a great help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably mean LPR, not LRC.

You need something like this: http://www.utexas.edu/academic/otl/software/lpr/

Comment: I couldn't download it from that site, paid or otherwise. I've tried that place already, hence this question.